# Получение случайного элемента из словаря для параметризации тестов

Tags: python, случайные-числа, dict, pytest

Столкнулся с такой сложностью для генерации тестовых данных в pytest.
Вычитываю пару "ключ-значение" из текстового файла (json), и с помощью yield передаю ее в фикстуру pytest следующим образом:

```
def read_list():
    with open(config.testfile) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    dct = {line['fullname']: line['val'] for line in data}
    for res in dct:
        yield res, dct[res]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('name, val', read_list())
def test_task_waiting(driver, name, val):
    assert create_task(driver, name, val)
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при повторном запуске тест запускается параметрами в одном и том же порядке, в котором они находятся в исходном json-файле.
Каким образом можно подавать на вход тестовой функции случайный элемент из словаря dct? Пробовал random.choice, но он возвращает случайное значение только один раз, с лету решить задачу не удалось.

Comment: Вообще говоря, тесты не должны оперировать случайными данными. К примеру, RNG может на протяжении нескольких тестов не выдать ни одного четного числа, (которое бы сломало код). А когда выдаст, вам придется лишний раз поломать голову, почему раньше тесты проходили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно на каждой итерации случайно выбирать один элемент с помощью `choice`, и удалять его из словаря - например, в данном случае это удобно сделать с помощью `pop`:

```
import random

def read_list():
    dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
    while dct:
        key = random.choice(list(dct.keys()))
        value = dct.pop(key)
        yield key, value

print([item for item in read_list()])
```

Либо можно просто перемешать элементы словаря:

```
import random

def read_list():
    dct = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
    items = list(dct.items())
    random.shuffle(items)
    for (key, value) in items:
        yield key, value

print([item for item in read_list()])
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!
Интересно, что под unix проблема оказалась неактуальна - при каждом запуске мой исходный вариант каждый раз выдает случайный параметр, под маком же потребовался предложенный апдейт.

Comment: Да, это может зависеть от интерпретатора. Вообще, для словаря не гарантируется сохранение порядка элементов. Но некоторые интерпретаторы реализуют внутреннюю механику словаря таким образом, что порядок сохраняется. Впрочем, нужно понимать, что даже если в словаре не сохраняется порядок, то это будет не полноценное случайное перемешивание. Поэтому если хочется действительно случайного порядка - то в любом случае лучше перемешать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что словарь структура данных не подходящая для "случайного" изъятия. Положите переменные в списки, например:

```
arg = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}
```

Назначайте в коде значения для переменных из указанных в json перед тестом:

```
import random
a = arg["a"][random.randint(0, len(arg["a"]) - 1)]
b = arg["b"][random.randint(0, len(arg["b"]) - 1)]
print a, b
# 1, 5
```